# How to import appcompat-v7 using Intellij

Tags: android, intellij-idea, material-design

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar
```

Is showing up in the red and is not being recognized. This is what I've done:

Downloaded support libraries using SDK manager

Went into project structure to add a new library, selected the appcompat-v7-23.4.0-javadoc.jar and appcompat-v7-23.4.0-sources.jar files in the 23.4.0 folder of appcompat-7.

After selecting OK, appcompat-v7-23.4.0-sources was added to my library.

Then I went to Modules -> Dependencies to make sure that appcompat-v7-23.4.0-sources was selected and hit OK.

It didn't work...? That line is still not recognized and the library isn't even showing up in my libs folder. I've tried another way where I copy the .jar files, paste them into my libs folder, and then right click to Add to Library from there but the same thing happens. How can I get this to work? My min is set to 7, target 21 and max 23 in the manifest. The error in styles.xml is, "Cannot resolve symbol".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"></style>
    <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I have tried to rebuild my project and when I do I get the following errors:

```
Information:5/26/16, 12:29 PM - Compilation completed with 4 errors and 0 warnings in 4s 99ms
/Users/accudeveloper/Android-App-2.0/android2.0/res/values/styles.xml
Error:(5, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android2.0] /Users/accudeveloper/Android-App-2.0/android2.0/res/values/styles.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar'.
Error:(8, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android2.0] /Users/accudeveloper/Android-App-2.0/android2.0/res/values/styles.xml:8: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'.
Error:(6, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android2.0] /Users/accudeveloper/Android-App-2.0/android2.0/res/values/styles.xml:6: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'.
Error:(7, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android2.0] /Users/accudeveloper/Android-App-2.0/android2.0/res/values/styles.xml:7: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimaryDark'.
```

This is where I found the .jar files. Does this path seem correct?

**android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7**

Based on answers for related questions on this site there should be a appcompat/res/values directory as well but I'm not seeing that.

Comment: What is the reason to not to use FREE ANDROID STUDIO which is intelliJ-Idea on steroids with support from GOOGLE?

Comment: A few tutorials I followed used IntelliJ so I just stuck with it. But all of this is giving me a headache already. I might end up up giving Android Studio a try.

Comment: Again, Android Studio using same core, same shortcuts, same interface. And there is no need to uninstall IDEA, you can have few instances  of Android Studios installed.

Comment: Yeah I'm using Gradle now and everything is working 100% better now. Trial and error I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Try to compile this dependency in your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies
    {
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    }
```

and after syncing try to clean your project

Comment: I do not have that file in my project only build.xml.

Comment: then you need to copy the library jar file to your libs folder and add it to your project from there

Comment: Thanks but I have tried that already and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Compile your GRADLE. The green one besides the android avd (looks like map marker) or try to rebuild your project.

If still exist, remove them. Rebuild your project and paste the gradle below.

compile 'com.android.support.appcompat-v7:23.4.0'

You can find it here.

[image]

Sorry for poor quality images.

Try to remove the style the App THEME. Above your Theme.AppCompat and
As what I see your style name="AppTheme.Base" - remove .Base

Result will be like this.
[image]

Comment: you can also use printscreen(PrtSc) to get snapshot of the screen

Comment: I'm using my phone, cellular data. I'll try

Comment: Thank you for the images but I tried to rebuild the project and got the following error:
Error:(5, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android2.0] /Users/accudeveloper/Android-App-2.0/android2.0/res/values/styles.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar'.

When I started this project I choose Android only and didn't use the Gradle: Android module.

Comment: I tried that and still didn't work.
@android:style/Theme.Material.Light
Works just fine however. I guess AppCompat is still not imported correctly some how?

Comment: Make a new Android project, put those styles what I posted above. And complie your gradle there also. This is for testing only if your library is installed on your Android Studio.

Comment: I'm not using Android Studio though, I'm using IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Android Studio is developed by Intelij, It's is the official IDE for Android. Take advantage of using Gradle. :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up trashing the entire project and creating a new one, this time starting the Android application and making sure Gradle was included alongside it and my code from before worked immediately with all of the dependencies I would need already included. Much easier this way. No idea what I was doing before (I don't think I was even grabbing the right folder from the Android SDK as the folder I actually needed is considered obsolete apparently - Android Support Library) but I'll be using Gradle from now on for my projects. Thanks to everyone who tried to help.